# Has Zoro ever called Sanji by his name?

Tags: one-piece

I was rewatching One Piece, and I see that Sanji is the only crew member who is recruited without Zoro being around. Their strength and rivalry aside, what is most fun is the nicknames they keep calling each other with.

Strangely, I can't seem to find any instance where Zoro calls Sanji by his name. Has there been an instance where Zoro refers to Sanji by his name?

Comment: No. It wouldn't be fun if they were nice enough to each other to be calling first names. 'Pervert kappa' is the best nickname Sanji could get from Zorro.

Comment: Nope, so far he has never called him by his name, it was even referenced in a SBS with oda: http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/SBS_Volume_73#Chapter_729.2C_Page_162

Comment: @Proxy  Please put that as an answer... that is an awesome answer. Mr. Nosebleed....damn

Comment: Great find Proxy. Guess I was not the only one wondering. That dude actually got the number of different names... Now to find the new ones after the question!

Comment: Also, I see a couple downvotes. Constructive Crtitcism is always appreciated so please free to suggest Edits for improving the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nope, so far he has never called him by his name, it was even referenced in a SBS with oda: [SBS Volume 73, Chapter 729, Pg. 162](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/SBS_Volume_73#Chapter_729.2C_Page_162)
The user counted (with frequency) the various names that Zoro and Sanji used for each other. This was covered till Volume 66 of the manga so far.

Original quote and Editor Notes below: *D: Dokusha (Reader);  O: Oda*

> **D**: Zoro and Sanji are always fighting! I was reading One Piece and thought it was odd that Zoro never seems to refer Sanji by his name, so I went back and checked!  I counted them up from Volume 5 to 66! Here are the results, ranked by frequency!!![..] In conclusion, Sanji does in fact refer to Zoro by name, but Zoro does not return the favor! P.N. Little Marron 
>   **O**: ...Okay. Thank you very much, Little Marron! So you counted them all... This was very fun to read! Some of these terms made me wonder when they'd said these things. Indeed, I have trouble imagining Zoro calling him "Sanji" by name. Not once, eh? Wow. Well, they might not get along well, but they're both valuable, trustworthy men who have Luffy's back. So let's forgive them their squabbles (laughs). 
>   **Page 162: In the VIZ Manga, Zoro does call Sanji by his name a few times for the sake of context, but he does not say "Sanji" explicitly in the original Japanese.**

Comment: Great find! I was tempted to go over the series again just to get an answer... you saved me quite some time!

Comment: Since link only answers are frowned upon, I edited a bit. Feel free to modify/revert. Nice find.

Comment: I see. No worries i'm glad it was helpful, but the credit goes to the user who was willing to go through the manga and count all the name references :P